# How can I save a string to a new line in a text file. Python

Tags: python-3.x

Hello I want to create a random password generator. I want it to save the passwords to a text file. I have already created the program, but I cant figure out how to split the inputs in the text file by a new line.

```
import random

letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 
'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 
'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 
'X', 'Y', 'Z']
numbers = ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
symbols = ['!', '#', '$', '%', '&', '(', ')', '*', '+']

print("Welcome to the PyPassword Generator!")
nr_letters = int(input("How many letters would you like in your password?\n")) 
nr_symbols = int(input(f"How many symbols would you like?\n"))
nr_numbers = int(input(f"How many numbers would you like?\n"))

pass_list = []

for let in range(1, nr_letters + 1):
   pass_list += random.choice(letters)

for num in range(1, nr_numbers + 1):
   pass_list += random.choice(numbers)

for sym in range(1, nr_symbols + 1):
   pass_list += random.choice(symbols)

random.shuffle(pass_list)
a = open("test.txt", "a+")
text = a.readlines()

strings = "".join(pass_list)
print(strings)
a.write(strings)

a.close()
```

The only problem with the code is that it saves it to the text file with no space between the passwords and I don't know how to do that. I know it is a stupid question but please help me!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\n` to indicate a line break. You use this expression already in the input requests in your code.
In Python you can concatenate strings with "+".

Therefore, in your code, modifying `a.write(strings)` to `a.write(strings+'\n')` will generate a line break after an entry was made.

Likewise, if you'd like to split passwords with spaces, you can concatenate a space string `a.write(strings+' ')`